# Adjust SubView constraints on a UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints, subview

I have an UITableView with 2 section. The first section (**VoucherCell**) will be filled with data from a database. The second section (**KodeVoucherCell**) will be filled with data inputted by the user using a simple form. I create that simple form as a SubView (see picture below).

[image]

Then I set the second section to load the SubView using the code below :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell.init()

    if(indexPath == NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1)) {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("KodeVoucherCell")!
        cell.addSubview(inputKodeVoucherSubView)
    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("VoucherCell")!

        cell.indentationLevel = indexPath.length - 1
        cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Voucher A"
    }

    return cell
}
```

Now the problem is, although I have set the constraints of the SubView, while I run the app, it looks like this :

[image]

How to fix this? I tried to modify the constraint but still get the same look. Thanks.

Comment: ¿did you set the size of the row to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`?

Comment: @calql8edkos: I tried, but can't resolve the problem.

Comment: ¿would you mind packing a project that reproduces the error and sharing?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be adding subviews directly to a UITableViewCell. Add them to the cell's `contentView`. Replace:

```
cell.addSubview(inputKodeVoucherSubView)
```

with:

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(inputKodeVoucherSubView)
```